# Do eight-square representations have patterns like four-square representations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

It is well-known that every positive integer can be written as the sum of the squares of four integers. More nuanced patterns are also known — for example, every odd positive integer has a representation as the sum of the squares of four integers which sum to $1$.

Evidently, every positive integer can also be written as the sum of the squares of eight integers (the trivial case being the addition of four $0^2$ terms, but non-trivial representations usually exist as well).

This leads me to the following question:

> QUESTION: Are there any known “interesting” patterns for the representations of positive integers as the sum of the squares of eight integers?

Comment: N9t sure, but it might be worth knowing that the sum of $k$ squares and the sum of the $k$ roots together determine the mean and deviation of the set of the roots.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Interesting! Do you have a good reference for that result? Or even a nice clear numerical example?

Comment: It's a fairly simple result. You can just write out the formulas. The relation between the sum and mean is pretty obvious

Comment: "which sum to 1." This confuses me.

Comment: @Peter: $13 = 3^2+(-2)^2+0^2+0^2$ and $3+(-2)+0+0=1$.